# CakePHP 2.x fails to update fields recently added to a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-2.x

I have a cake application which has a table named `realestate_properties` in its database. I added two columns i.e. `latitude` and `longitude` to this table.

On the HTML form there are already many fields, I just added the two fields named `latitude` and `longitude`. Now when I am submitting the data, it's only adding the other fields which are already available. There is no effect on new fields.

Please suggest a good solution. Do I need to define the new column names anywhere in addition to the HTML form and database table?

CakePHP version is 2.4.1

Comment: Please include the code you're using to insert the data.

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause for the behavior you mention is CakePHP failing to refresh the cached schema of your models stored in

```
/app/tmp/cache/models
```

This may happen if you've made changes to the database but haven't switched debugging on.

Try turning debug to 2 by editing `/app/Config/core.php` and setting

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Next time you access your action, CakePHP should refresh the cache.

If this doesn't solve your problem, try deleting the contents of

```
/app/tmp/cache/models
/app/tmp/cache/persistent
```

But only the contents, don't deleted the folder structure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes cache has to be cleared, All files under model folder and 'myapp_cake_core_method_cache' file under persistent folder.

```
tmp/cache/models/*
tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_method_cache
```